Get components of feature in Bootstrapper application
I can get feature information in the Bootstrapper application using "WixPackageFeatureInfo" which is present in BootstrapperApplicationData.xml.
Components information is not available in BootstrapperApplicationData.xml. How do I access components of features?

https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/8813
